# Как правильно подключить БД?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

Ловлю ошибку

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C: \Users\dayover\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\TestDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

```
   @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\dayover\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Искал в интернете, пишет надо:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myuniquedb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Base.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

Получаю ошибку:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Путь брал из : обозреватель серверов->Моя база -> Свойства -> Строка подключения.

Comment: если вместо `AttachDbFilename=C:..\TestDB.mdf;` указать `Initial Catalog=TestDB;` работает?

Comment: Посмотрите ответ [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479730/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-sql-server-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Сам файл базы-то существует?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка означает, что база с именем TestDB уже существует.

Механизм подключения баз через AttachDbFilename ненадежен (т.к. приходится угадывать, подключена ли база, или еще нет). Не используйте его. Ну или по крайней мере явно задайте имя базы в строке подключения. Судя по всему, с именем инстанса вы угадали, так что нужно задать только само имя базы - как Initial Catalog или Database:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\dayover\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

или

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=mydatabase;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\dayover\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException". 
Дополнительные сведения: Cannot attach the file 'C: \Users\dayover...  as database 'TestDB'.

Comment: @LittleFox значит, действительно не может. скорее всего у аккаунта, под которым работает SQL Express, нет прав на доступ к папке. Выдайте права Everyone, full control, чтобы проверить.

Comment: Пришлось опять залазить в обозреватель серверов->Моя база -> Свойства -> Строка подключения. И все опять заработало. И так каждый раз когда я заново открываю проект...

Answer (score 0):

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Назв_базы;User ID=имя_входа" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```