# Подключение к SQL Server на C# для чайника

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate поставил, вместе с ней поставился SQL Server 2012.
Итак.

Задача: подключиться к **SQL Server**, создать **новую локальную** базу данных, выполнить скрипт создания базы из файла "database.sql" (создание таблиц, процедур и т. п.).

```cs
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=testdb;");
sqlConnection.Open();

MyClass.scriptExecute(sqlConnection, "database.sql");

sqlConnection.Close();
sqlConnection.Dispose();
```

Проблема: судя по всему, в строке подключения, а скорее всего - в имени сервера.

Объясните на пальцах, пожалуйста, что там писать? В голове каша, не понимаю ни фига.
Перепробовал варианты названия сервера с [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) и [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) - все время какие-то ошибки. Варианты: localhost, (localhost), (local), localdb, (localdb), (localdb)\v.11, еще какие-то были, и уже совершенно запутался в них всех. Есть варианты подключения к Server Instance - это что еще за хрень? Тоже не пойму.
Как мне объяснили, логин-пароль указывать не надо при создании базы, кажется, используется аутенфикация Windows, но я опять же толком не понял о чем речь.

Спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: давайте начнем с того, как имя инстанса вашего сервера? ну или на худой конец давайте выясним, какая редакция сервера у вас установлена, думаю что это даже не Express. В общем надо больше информации именно по установленному серверу

Comment: Если вместе со студией поставился, то скорее всего экспресс редакция. Для него достаточно просто указать имя инстанса, например так "\mssqlexpress"

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya не помню какая версия ставится с 12 студией, но скорее всего это все же MsSQL LocalDB, а для нее инстанс вообще не нужен, только ссылка на файл

Comment: @Dmitry и ссылка на файл не нужна. Ссылка на файл - это AttachDbFileName, фишка SQL Express и LocalDB. Просто базу в обоих версиях можно создать и без указания пути.

Comment: @PashaPash а чем отличается редакция Express от взрослой версии? Размером базы и стоимостью владения. Про создания файловой базы в Express честно говоря не помню. LocalDB интересен тем, что старт базы по требованию. файловые базы не юзал уже давно, так что мог и напутать

Comment: @Dmitry Express отличается зарезанным процессором, памятью и отсутствием агента (не умеет легко выполнять задачи по расписанию)

Comment: @PashaPash, кстати, у Express не факт что инстанс зовется SQLEXPRESS, при установке его можно задать как угодно, в том числе на значение по умолчанию - MSSQLSERVER

Comment: @Dmitry согласен. я расписал механизм узнавания имени инстанса в ответе

Comment: @PashaPash и еще момент, если в системе инстанс всего один и зовется MSSQLSERVER, то в конекшен стринге достаточно указать localhost или вообще 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Dmitry, "как имя инстанса вашего сервера" - мне бы тоже хотелось это узнать :D Я в комментариях под единственным ответом расписал свои попытки узнать его.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

У SQL Server есть два режима работы:

## Полноценный инстанс (именованный или неименованный).

Его наличие можно проверить в Control Panel / Services:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В скобках написано имя инстанса. MSSQLSERVER - это неименованный инстанс. Если у вас там написано SQLEXPRESS - то имя инстанса и есть SQLEXPRESS.

К таким инстансам можно подключится по имени в формате ИМЯСЕРВЕРА\ИМЯИНСТАНСА. Точка в имени сервера - это локальная машина. Т.е. для подключения к серверу со скриншота можно использовать

- `.`
- `localhost` - без скобок!
- `127.0.0.1`
- `pasha-pc` - имя моей машины.

Будь там написано SQLEXPRESS, для подключения можно было бы использовать

- `.\SQLEXPRESS`
- `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` - без скобок!
- `pasha-pc\SQLEXPRESS` - имя моей машины + имя инстанса.

Проблема с полноценным инстансом - доступ к нему нужно настраивать. Он по умолчанию разрешает доступ тому, кто устанавливал SQL Server, но всем остальным доступ нужно разрешить вручную. Для обхода этой проблемы существует второй режим работы:

## LocalDB

LocalDB - это легковесный инстанс SQL Server-а, который существует только для текущего пользователя.

Для подключения к нему используется имя сервера в формате `(localdb)\имяинстанса`.

Для создания новых инстансов или просмотра существующих можно использовать утилиту `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe` (точный путь зависит от установленной версии SQL Server)

Вот пример вывода существующих инстансов на моей машине

```
>SqlLocalDB.exe i
MSSQLLocalDB
ProjectsV12
v11.0
v11.m
v12.0
```

Соответствующие имена для подключения - `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`, `(localdb)\ProjectsV12`....

Обычно пару инстансов уже создано по умолчанию, в частности инстанс с текущей версией - поэтому вы встречаете упоминание `(localdb)\v11.0` в примерах - это инстанс, который почти наверное будет создан на машине с 2012-ой студией.

Воспользуйтесь панелью управления сервисами и SqlLocalDB, узнайте имя инстанса, и впишите соответствующее имя в connection string.

Comment: Ого, круто. [15 символов]

Comment: @PashaPash, да, еще последний вопрос.
Вы писали про варианты подключения к серверу: точка, localhost, 127.0.0.1, pasha-pc - зачем существует так много вариантов и есть ли разница?

Comment: @Max разницы нет, просто там указывается имя машины, на которой установлен sql server, и его можно указать разными способами.

Answer (score 7):

Что касается проверки подлинности для *SQL Server*. Существует [два режима](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms144284(v=sql.120).aspx#Anchor_1) проверки подлинности на *SQL Server-е*:

> 1. Проверка подлинности Windows
> 2. Проверка подлинности SQL Server.

Инстанс может быть настроен на оба режима подключения. 
Чтобы подключиться к *SQL Server-у* используя первый режим, в строке подключения необходимо передать

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Либо

```
Integrated Security=true;
```

В этом случае будет использоваться *встроенная безопасность*, проверка будет проходит под тем аккаунтом, под которым вы зарегистрированы в ОС. В строке подключения параметры имя пользователя *SQL Server-а* и пароль не учитываются и указывать их необязательно.

Если вы хотите зайти на *SQL Server* под конкретным пользователем, зарегистрированным на самом *SQL Server-е*, то тогда параметр `Integrated Security` пропускаете, либо указываете равным `false`, а параметры имя пользователя и пароль указываются с помощью приведенного ниже синтаксиса

```
User ID=*****;Password=*****;
```

Более подробно про синтаксис строки подключения в зависимости от режима проверки подлинности можно прочитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms254500(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ликбез.

Answer (score 2):

Итог. По идее можно было просто использовать вот это имя сервера (выделено красным). Если делать как в моем коде - то перед этим предварительно создав нужную базу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]