# ADO.NET Не удается подключиться к БД MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, ado.net

Есть БД, в консольном приложении C# пытаюсь плодключиться к БД и считать содержимое таблицы следующим образом:

```
string cs= @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True;";
string command = "SELECT * FROM Customers";                                        

DataTable customers = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    customers.Load(dr);
    dr.Close();
}
```

При попытке открытия соединения получаю ошибку

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "ShopDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\mail@yahoo.com'.'
```

Использую БД MS SQL Server Express 2016, ОС Windows 10, VS 2017. 
В БД Метод аутентификации выбран Windows Authentication.
При попытке указать в строке подключения имя пользователя, которое отображается при подключении к БД (в неактивных полях) и пароль, который соответствует этому пользователю, появляется ошибка

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'DESCTOP-5HGPGMV\username'.'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей строке подключения фигурирует `Integrated Security=True`. Это означает, что для подключения к SQL серверу будет использоваться логин пользователя, из-под которого запущена программа. Например, если программу запустит пользователь `mydomain\Ivanov`, то для подключения к MS SQL серверу будет использоваться логин `mydomain\Ivanov`, а если программу запустит `mydomain\Petrov` - то логин `mydomain\Ivanov`.

> При попытке указать в строке подключения имя пользователя, которое отображается при подключении к БД (в неактивных полях) и пароль, который соответствует этому пользователю

Логин и пароль в строке подключения для этого режима вводить не надо!

Просто запустите sql server management studio и в Security - Logins убедитесь, что пользователь  `DESCTOP-5HGPGMV\username` есть в списке **плюс имеет достаточные права к БД** вашего приложения.

[image: SSMS, security - logins]

Альтернативно, вы можете убрать Integrated security и вот тогда вам будет необходимо указать и логин и пароль от какой-либо учётки SQL Server.

Для общего понимания можете почитать вот эти вопросы на so:

- [Подключение к SQL Server на C# для чайника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480532/213987)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и особенно за ссылку, проблему я решил, изменив строку подключения. Кроме того, понял, что у меня было 3 экземпляра сервера: SQLEXPRESS, SQLEXPRESS01, MSSQLSERVER и я пытался подключиться не к тому, где создавал БД с таблицей.