# Не получается создать новую базу данных SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Читаю сейчас книгу Троелсена и при создании новой базы данных SQL Server возникла ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать ?

Comment: Указать верное имя сервера или установить его, если он отсутствует.

Comment: Сервер расположен локально? Попробуйте убрать из имени ".\"

Comment: И да, при нажатии на кновпку обновить у вас подтянутся доступные сервера, выберите в выпадающем списке необходимый.

Comment: посмотрите вот этот вопрос, может вам он будет полезен [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479730/Подключение-к-sql-server-на-c-для-чайника/480532#480532](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479730/Подключение-к-sql-server-на-c-для-чайника/480532#480532)

Comment: вот к нему и задубликатим. Там и про инстансы есть и про integrated security...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключение к SQL Server на C# для чайника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479730/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-sql-server-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, список пустой, кнопка "Обновить" не помогла.

Comment: Зайдите в сервисы и посмотрите как называется инстанс скуля. Подключение будет выглядеть как имя_машины + \ + имя_инстанса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я попробовал использовать следующее имя сервера: "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb"; и это сработало.